# Google Assistant Stopwatch

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, dialogflow-es

I am currently creating an app which should allow me to measure the time I take to do 50 pushups and save it to the database.

Currently when I am calling my app and saying "start" I create a timestamp and save it to the database. When I am finished I have to call my App again and say "stop" so it gets the last timestamp and calculates the difference.

Is there a better way to do this? It just feels so unnatural if you have to start the app twice. As far as I know there is no way to edit the "no-speak-timeout".

Thanks!

Comment: How about you wear an armband holder for your phone suitable for excercising and use the accelerometer in the device to keep track of the pushups?

Comment: EDIT(was first a answer): after I wrote I noticed its not exactly answer your question...

I guess you can try <break> as ssml tag?

So like <break time="360s"/> for 5 min timer. Or split it and say in the middle one minute finished, 2 minute finished etc.

Maybe it have some kind of max break time limit somewhen.
But you dont give timeout while you not speek

Comment: @shortQuestion but will i still be able to call an intent while this 5 minute answer is running? So if I am done, will I still be able to say "stop"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. Keeping the microphone open indefinitely isn't possible, and would be a bad idea. While it might make some sense in this case, the potential for abuse is pretty high.

Users *can* setup a shortcut, so they could just say "Hey Google, start" and "Hey Google, stop" as shortcuts to the full phrase that would trigger your action, but the Assistant would still go through the entire routine when replying. (ie - it would say "Ok, getting pushup master" and the chirp before your action would reply.)

Comment: What do you mean by "the Assistant would still go through the entire routine when replying"? In theory I could create a shortcut saying "Hey Google, stop" and map it to "Ask myApp to stop my pushup training", right? Btw this would also interfer with the command "Stop" when you want to stop music, right?

Comment: Answer clarified, slightly. Good question about interfering with stopping music. Probably.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! Then i'll have to go with the Shortcuts, hopefully there will be other possibilities in the future

Comment: If you wouldn't want interference with your music then you may use literal commands, where a statement like "Hey Google, stop", does exactly what you want it to and not necessarily interfering with music, except it is a reserved command already.